# Displaying cascaded ul as inline-block is not working

Tags: html, css

I want to display listed items (List 1) inside listed items (List 2) and I want the `<li>` elements of the first list to be displayed inline and the `<li>` elements inside each first `<li>` to be displayed vertically on hover. The problem that when hovering over the first main `<li>`, then the second main `<li>` will be displayed at the end of the first main `<li>` which is not expected:

[image]

The following is a live display of the problem:
 https://codepen.io/alafawzi/pen/PaVYyB

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

ul li ul li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    Html5 begins
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">div</a>
        <ul>
          <li>Link1.1</li>
          <li>Link1.2</li>
          <li>Link1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">head</a>
         <ul>
         <li>Link2.1</li>
          <li>Link2.2</li>
          <li>Link2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add absolute position in sub ul.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;  
}

ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    Html5 begins
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">div</a>
        <ul>
          <li>Link1.1</li>
          <li>Link1.2</li>
          <li>Link1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">head</a>
         <ul>
         <li>Link2.1</li>
          <li>Link2.2</li>
          <li>Link2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```